# How to Disconnect Source from Health App Using Health Kit?

Tags: ios, ios8, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I have made Connection from my existing app with Health App using Health Kit, Give Permission and Perform Read and Write Operation. Now I want to Disconnect my App from Health App. So is it Possible to disconnect using HealthKit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app cannot remove itself as a HealthKit source once it has become one.  If the user deletes the app from the device then they will be prompted to remove the data associated with the app, and they can also revoke the authorizations of the app by going to the Sources tab in Health.